# asp.net Dictionary<string,string> update item based on key value

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, dictionary

I have a Dictionary object:

```
protected Dictionary<string,string> myDict;
```

I would like to be able to search the dictionary via a key and update the value of that key/value pair.

```
if (!myDict.ContainsKey(key))
{
    myDict.Add(key, value); //if key is not found in the collection add it.
}
else //if it is found then update it.
{
    Update[Key].Value with myValue
}
```

Is there a way to do the above? How to update the value of a key by checking the key?
What is the actual code to match the pseudocode in the else statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
myDict[key] = value;
```

If dictionary already contains key, it is updated. Otherwise, it is created.

Comment: Ah yes. I was trying myDict.Keys[key] that's why it wasn't working. The syntax was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the value with the key and assign a new value:

```
myDict[myKey] = yourNewValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be straightforward if I understand you correctly:

```
if (!myDict.ContainsKey(key))
{
    myDict.Add(key, value); //if key is not found in the collection add it.
}
else //if it is found then update it.
{
    myDict[key] = value;
}
```